# Can we assume typed inputs?

Tags: discussion

For some languages with a static type system the compiler is able to infer the types, however sometimes there's ambiguity (even with input) unless the user gives the type manually:

#### Motivation 1: Haskell

Consider the following Haskell example:

```hs
f xs = do
  x <-randomRIO (toEnum 0, toEnum 1) -- random Enum-type
  return $ map (x==) xs              -- check for each input if it's equal
```

Now calling it with [`f [False,True]`](https://tio.run/##LYy9CsIwFEb3@xTf0KGFKronbgqdhOomDoGmGMxPuUkgPn0M4nY4HM5Lxbe2tlbjtsAJt09M2u1n5ZfgiFaUCIklEFDEDvzz83RFn8LZZ4fDiD8dhxaxTpk9OvRFygGiO7UDkVPGt8/GxidIIbDicVE26vHOWT9r/QI) succeeds because the type-checker can tell the type of the input - namely `[Bool]`.

However, calling it with an empty list [`f []`](https://tio.run/##LYwxC8IwFAb39yu@oUMLKronbg5OQh3FIdAUg31JeXmF@OtjELfjOO7l8tsvS62B1ySK@yer58Po4pSYaEbJsJgSAcXsIT8/Xm/oNV3ixjju8KfT0CLxuklEh75YO8B053YgYhdi@6wSosIagxmPZ61f) won't work because the compiler has no idea what kind of list it is.

Now we could call it with [`f ([] :: [Bool])`](https://tio.run/##LYyxCsMgGAZ3n@IbMii0pV2Ddihk6FRIx5BBiKFS9Q9qwD69ldLtOI576fQ2ztVq/UYx4/lJ2fjTqMNCnrEVJUFhIQYUeUT8@fH@AM80hN3jfMCfLqJF0eQ9BnTgRSkB2V3bgTGvbWifLdqQoaTECj7N6HtMNyI3i1q/) explicitly giving the compiler the type and it would work. Or even worse (byte-wise) we could just give the function `f` a type: [`f :: [Bool] -> IO [Bool]`](https://tio.run/##LYyxCoMwGIT3PMUNDgq12FUSh0KHTgU7ikPASEOT/JJEiE@fhuJ2x333fWT4KmNy1nYjH/E@QlT2Okq3kGVsRd9juhOZGe2A5@ssZUgBAgsxIPEW/n8YC1BHerjdorvgTLemQF7F3TtUqJMQDXg1FANjVmpXPJvXLkJwjhXTnPMP).

---

#### Motivation 2: Rust

A similar scenario could cause troubles in Rust, consider:

```rust
let f = |l| { l };  // identity function
```

Again calling it with [`f(vec!(101))`](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/Py1PITcxM09DU6GaS0EhJ7VEIU3BVqEmp0ahWiFHodaaCyhaUJSZV5KTp6ihVG1lX6uko5CmUZaarKhhaGCoqalpzVX7/z8A) won't cause any trouble.

However calling it with an empty vector [`f(vec!())`](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/Py1PITcxM09DU6GaS0EhJ7VEIU3BVqEmp0ahWiFHodaaCyhaUJSZV5KTp6ihVG1lX6uko5CmUZaarKihqalpzVX7/z8A) will error.

Again we could solve it by using a typed input:

```rust
let v : Vec<i32> = Vec::new(); f(v)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYo7DoAgEAV7TvG0gsRKO/zdwt4YSEhwYxSxQM6OW9hNZua8r1CKJeyrI6mQBOBNgMWI179I8Mi9@G2ExmK2wXXtxAOj1mQeqXoejtNR8FTJOuk51w2sjIpLLuUD)

Or we give the closure a type: [`|l : Vec<i32>| { l };`](https://tio.run/##Dcq9CoAgFAbQ3af4dFJoqk37eYv2EAXBJMxa1Ge/deaTn7sQ@YTzCEkqVAZEV@CxoEVo7M7OYRrXhoqIbtgfrhxSiYlLUfXWxQAvX2e5VEoZ1ok@)

### Questions

Often these issues arise with empty lists/vectors etc. - my questions are:

- Can we assume that the inputs carry a type (like `[] :: [Bool]` or `let v : Vec<i32> = Vec::new()` in the examples above?
- Can we assume that there is an implicit annotation (in case the challenge specifies sth. along the lines "*given a list of integers*")?

If none of these are answered with *yes*, can we work out a system to count bytes for giving the input a type (eg. in Haskell this is shorter), so something like:

- the function is [67 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRCG4srgkNVcvKDEvJT@XK02hwlbDRsWuQlNPw9ZWE8gqAksEefprlOS75pXmKhjoQBmGmv9zEzPzFGwVCooy80oUbG1sFNIUNKJjrayinfLzc2I1/wMA)
- annotating costs: `::[Bool]` 8 bytes

Total byte count is 65 bytes, or something else?